# Can't ping self

Tags: apache-2.2, mac-osx, web-server, ping

I have a wireless internet connection setup on my Mac. (v10.5.6) Am connected to the internet and everything is running smoothly. I recently discovered a quirky behaviour while setting up apache web server. When i typed in my dynamic ip (http://117.254.149.11/) in the webbrowser to visit my site pages it just timed out. In terminal i tried pinging localhost and it worked.

> $ ping localhost
>
> PING localhost (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
>
> 64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.063 ms
>
> 64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.056 ms
>
> 64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.044 ms

But if i pinged my ip it would just time out.

> $ ping 117.254.149.11
>
> PING 117.254.149.11 (117.254.149.11): 56 data bytes
>
> ^C
>
> --- 117.254.149.11 ping statistics ---
>
> 10 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss

Pinging any other site works though.

I am completely stumped.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is 117.254.149.11 address listed in `ifconfig -a`? If it is not, then it is probably the external IP of the router and you have to configure on your router a port forwarding rule for port TCP/80 and may be also for TCP/443 and redirect them to the IP configured on the enternet interface of your MAC.

Comment: it does list when i do ifconfig -a. 
This is what i get:
 > ppp0: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
 inet 117.254.149.11 --> 192.168.52.12 netmask 0xff000000 
Still i am not able to ping 117.254.149.11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure that Apache is listening on your WLAN card's IP address: `LISTEN ...` (where ... is the address from Network Preferences -> AirPort -> Advanced... -> TCP/IP -> IPv4 Address). You can configure this in Apache's config files - their location in the file system depends on your Apache installation (search for httpd.conf, the config files should be in that directory and its subdirectories).
2. Is `http://117.254.149.11/` the dynamic ip of your router or the dynamic ip of your Mac? If it's the one from your router, you'll have to configure NAT to forward to your Mac.

Comment: Unfortunately i don't use a WLAN card. Mine is a USB dongle based hispeed wireless connection. I made no ip configurations at all but instead installed few kexts to get it working. I checked if my port 80 is open and it is. Can you please tell me how i can configure NAT to forward to my Mac?

Comment: First you should somehow find out the IP of your USB WLAN stick. I'd personally use ifconfig on the terminal. It should usually have an IP starting with either 10. or starting with 192.168. Then try to connect to that instead of 117.254.149.11. Only when that works, you should continue to configure NAT.

Comment: This is what i get with ifconfig:
ppp0: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
 inet 117.254.149.11 --> 192.168.52.12 netmask 0xff000000.

................................................................
Even 192.168.52.12 doesn't ping. Its so weird.

Comment: Ah, so it's not an USB WLAN stick either, but rather something like an UMTS or GPRS stick? (Probably that's what you meant in your previous comment - hispeed wireless connection can mean several things :-) Unfortunately, I have no experience with those, and I don't know enough about PPP - but in that case, you sure won't have to do NAT on your router - since there probably is no such router on your home network then :-)

Comment: Yes you got me right! its an EVDO setup. Dint know if everyone was familiar with the term so was more generic. As theres no way i can think of to port forward or configure a static ip. But one thing though.. i had windows running on the same machine before and everything was running smoothly. With the same damn setup! :( Had to migrate to Mac cos i m into Rails and most gem support is on Mac and not on Windows. I love Mac but not having a public web server running makes me feel completely paralyzed!

Comment: Oh by the way.. "running smoothly" means i could ping my dynamic ip and also run my web server with it being accessible publicly using the same dynamic ip. Forgot to mention that. And i got all this working without any additional configuration on Windows.

Comment: Can you ping it from a different device on the internet?

Comment: No! It just doesn't ping. Infact you would be a better judge. Please try pinging my comp. The ip is now: 117.254.109.64

Comment: It pings: PING 117.254.109.64 (117.254.109.64): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 117.254.109.64: icmp_seq=0 ttl=51 time=650.080 ms

Comment: Wow! ok. but then why am i not able to configure settings on dyndns or no-ip to redirect hostname to this ip?

Comment: Can you also please check in your browser by pasting the ip. You should see a apache web server page. If yes then my question is answered. :)

Comment: Probably the dyndns entry works. But since your machine will resolve the ip from the hostname first, before sending a request, it's just as good as sending a request to the ip directly (when accessing the site from your machine). Hm, I don't know, why it's not possible to ping 117.254.109.64 from your machine. It seems that Windows routed the packets differently. I don't know, what your Mac setup currently does.

Comment: Yes, I can see the apache page.

Comment: Hmm. If outside sources can access my site i am more than happy. That will atleast solve my problem for now. Did you try checking in your browser?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the OSX firewall is disabled

Comment: I am a newbie to mac. How do i disable the firewall? if it is as the one found in "System Preferences" i have done that already.

Comment: The default firewall rules include Block LocalNetworks to/from 172.0.0.x.  You're trying to ping 117.254.149.11 from 127.0.0.1.

Answer (score 1):

You run into one of the most popular network issues called 'packet loop'.
There is few options for You:

- Set up routing tables on your gateway (requires skills)
- Add couple of entries in `/etc/hosts` for Linux or `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` for Windows or `/private/etc/hosts` for OSX for every workstation that will connect to your server using domain name:

  192.168.1.100 xxx.com
  192.168.1.100 www.xxx.com

  , where 192.168.1.100 is local address of your server (replace 127.0.0.1 if service running on local machine). This way your workstation will translate domain name into the local address (and not query the DNS and get external one).

Comment: How to edit the hosts file in Mac OS X – Leopard : http://decoding.wordpress.com/2009/04/06/how-to-edit-the-hosts-file-in-mac-os-x-leopard/

Comment: This is what /etc/hosts reads in my mac system:


> ##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1 localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost 
fe80::1%lo0 localhost

By the way i don't have a static ip. Only dynamic ip.

Comment: Just add the new line `127.0.0.1 www.whatever.com` and try to ping it.

Comment: OK. Can i map my dynamic ip to a DDNS hostname? But i have to change it manually everytime i suppose.

Comment: If you want to serve web pages using dynamic ip, consider using no-ip.org or similar free services.

Comment: Hm, what does this have to do with domain names, I thought the question was about IP addresses?

Comment: I was kind of curious myself, since my answer was dinged with a vote down for asking where he was getting his IP address. It sounds more like he is trying to ping an address external to his machine/internal network, so he'd have to make sure his port forwarding is enabled (and his provider isn't firewalling it).

Answer (score 1):

Silly question, but where are you getting the IP address from? The network control panel? You double and triple checked it's not a typo?

That address doesn't look like a typical internal address. Check the Mac's network settings to double check what the interface's IP address is. If that's an external address you'll need to have port forwarding enabled for it to work.

Comment: Saw I had a downvote earlier (and no comment why) but wondered if this is an external router address, he needs his port forwarding enabled. His preference panel should give him his IP address within his network, and if he can connect to *that* (http://192.168.x.x) then the problem lays with his router, most likely.